# Dynamically determining table name given field name in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Strange situation: I am trying to remove some hard coding from my code. There is a situation where I have a field, lets say "CityID", and using this information, I want to find out which table contains a primary key called CityID.

Logically, you'd say that it's probably a table called "City" but it's not... that table is called "Cities". There are some other inconsistencies in database naming hence I can never be sure if removing the string "ID" and finding out the plural will be sufficient.

Note: Once I figure out that CityID refers to a table called Cities, I will perform a join to replace CityID with city name on the fly. I will appreciate if someonw can also tell me how to find out the first varchar field in a table given its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you seek is all available in the [information schema views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204%28SQL.80%29.aspx). Note that you will find many sources telling you how to directly query the underlying system tables that these are views onto - and I must admit that I do the same when it's just to find something out quickly - but the recommended way for applications is to go through these views.

For example, to find your `CityID` column:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'CityID'
```

To find the first `varchar` field in a table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
    AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'    -- This is off the top of my head!
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: Can I figure out if the column is a PK or FK? Currently it returns multiple tables as ~30 tables have this field as FK but only one has this field as PK.

Comment: @Salman A : for that I think you want to look in `TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` and `CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE` (or maybe `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`). These views tend to be fairly readable in terms of working out what goes where; have a look around the docs I linked.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'THE_COLUMN_NAME' )
```

To get column information from the specified table:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'myTable'
```

Comment: Good, query 1 gives me multiple tables since various tables have CityID as a FK. Is it possibility to shortlist the table that has it as the PK.

Comment: For that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222217/how-do-i-determine-if-a-column-is-in-the-primary-key-of-its-table-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name='CityID'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables to read metadata about the database.

```
SELECT 
     TABLE_NAME 
FROM 
     [db].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE 
     COLUMN_NAME='CityID';
```

For a primer in what's in the INFORMAITON_SCHEMA, see [INFORMATION_SCHEMA, a map to your database](http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20561)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, you want to find tables which contain CITYID column in primary key

You can use SQL Server system views like **sysindexes** and sysindexkeys as shown in SQL tutorial to [query database table primary keys](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/find-tables-list-with-primary-key-including-specific-column-name.aspx) including [composite primary keys](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/create-composite-primary-key-with-multiple-columns.aspx) which are formed

```
SELECT
  TBL.name as TableName
FROM sysobjects as PK
INNER JOIN sys.objects as TBL
  on TBL.object_id = PK.parent_obj
INNER JOIN sysindexes as IND
  on IND.name = PK.name AND
  IND.id = TBL.object_id
INNER JOIN SysIndexKeys as KEYS
  on KEYS.id = IND.id AND
  KEYS.indid = IND.indid
INNER JOIN syscolumns as COL
  on COL.id = KEYS.id AND
  COL.colid = KEYS.colid
WHERE
  PK.xtype = 'PK' AND
  COL.name = 'CityID'
```