# Compare Two Tables In two Databases with the same Table Structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update, subquery

I have two databases `Database_1` and `Database_2`. Both of these two databases have the table `asset_table` with the same columns and same table structure. But there is some extra data in `Database_2` `asset_table` than in `Database_1` `asset_table`.

I need to update some columns in extra data in "Database_2" as '0'.

Here is my update query.

```
Update Database_2.q2m1.asset_table
set min_qty = 0, max_qty = 0, unit_cost = '0.00'
```

I need a query to check what are the extra data are included in `Database_2` and not in `Database_1`.

The primary key for both tables is `asset_is`. Then update the data.

Could anyone help me with a script for this?

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606175/how-to-compare-data-between-two-table-in-different-databases-using-sql-server-20

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: oracle, sqlserver, postgresql...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare data between two table in different databases using Sql Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606175/how-to-compare-data-between-two-table-in-different-databases-using-sql-server-20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
update a2
set min_qty = 0, max_qty = 0, unit_cost = 0 
from database2.asset_table a2
where not exists (
    select 1 from database1.asset_table a1 where a1.asset_id = a2.asset_id
)
```